# Spring Rest Controller - Empty and wrong JSON inputs

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have Rest controller what registering users (creating User and Profile database row).
I need to secure inputs to not receive empty `{}` and wrong attributes JSONs.

My Controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void register(@RequestBody User user) {
        try {
            userService.persist(user);
        } catch (TransactionSystemException e) {
            throw new PersistenceException(e.getOriginalException());
        }
    }
}
```

When I send for example `{}` or `{"bad_data:420"}` It crashes somewhere where I hashing password what is way far from where it needs to be stopped.

How to do it to throw exception somewhere before casting into object or before persisting?

Comment: take a look at this article [Spring Validation](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/spring-boot-handling-exceptionserrors-restful-api-abdelghani-roussi/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [bean validation API](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/) to valid the user input.
It integrates smoothly enough with Spring Controllers.

So here are the steps :

1) Annotate the model to validate (`User` class) with the constraints you wish (`@NotNull` or `@NotEmpty` for example on the fields.
2) Add the `@Valid` annotation on the parameter to validate.
3) Optionally add a `Error` parameter to capture the errors.

For example :

**Model**

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class User {

   @NotEmpty
   private String userName;

   @NotEmpty
   private String password;

   // ...
}
```

**Controller**

```
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import javax.validation.Valid;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void register(@Valid @RequestBody User user, Errors errors) {

    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
      // error input processing here
    }

    try {
        userService.persist(user);
    } catch (TransactionSystemException e) {
        throw new PersistenceException(e.getOriginalException());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I was searching for! One more question,when I already have annotation `@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)` means that I am not supposted to use `@NotEmpty` or I need?

Comment: and second last question :D How to validate nested Objects?